# How can I insert an element on a View Controller without modifying the rest of constraints?

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a problem that makes me to waste a lot of time. Each time I insert an element on a `View Controller` (e.g `UITextField`, `UIButton`, etc) and I have set the constraints for the rest of elements on the `View Controller` I have to delete all the constraints and add new ones because the new element brokes the structure of the screen position of the elements (it modifies all the constraints also).

I spend a lot of time each time I have to change something on a screen of my `Swift` application because each time I modify something I have to add all the constraints again.

Is there a way in which I can insert an element ignoring the rest of elements and then position this new element according to one or more of the elements on the screen? Or something to do that the constraints will ignore the new element until I have set it correctly? Or some similar workaround?

**P.S:** According to the comments, as it seems that my question is not very clear, I am going to add some additional info:

- I am trying to insert the new element when I am designing the application.
- I am using the `Main.storyboard` file to insert the new elements.
- I drag the elements into the `View Controller`.
- I am using `XCode`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: but are we talking about inserting a view in a ViewController when the app is up and running? or in designer? it is not clear to me (I think the answer is the first)

Comment: @Aaron I am using XCode if this is what you mean.

Comment: @ddb When I am designing it. Should I add more info on the question? What would be relevant for the rest of people?

Comment: how do you insert view in the VC? and we are talking about storyboard or xib?

Comment: @ddb about storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can still let Xcode create constraints for you, it works fine most of the time. Just select in the menu:

```
Editor > Resolve AutoLayout Issues > Reset to suggested constraints
```

After doing this you still can change a few of the constraints to fit your needs.

---

In general, you drop all of your views in your controller and set constraints only at the end.

As [@Anand K mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39286539/1392046), Stack views are a great way to layout your app  plus it's strongly encouraged by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraints with code to have a precise position for all elements in your view. This is an example:

1) for a label called **userNameLabel**:

```
userNameLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
                userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
                userNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(220).active = true
                userNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
```

2) for another label called **albumNameLabel**:

```
albumNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(220).active = true
                albumNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
                albumNameLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(userNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
                albumNameLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
```

3) **remember** this before you put your constraints:

```
self.addSubview(userNameLabel)
self.addSubview(albumNameLabel)
```

And go on in this way to all elements in your View.